# Sort 2D array by specific row

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I want to sort a 2x3 array by the second row in ascending order. The values of the first row must change position accordingly.

E.g.

```
1 3 5
4 2 6
```

should become

```
3 1 5
2 4 6
```

The code:

```
int[][] values = {{1, 5, 3},
                  {4, 6, 2}};
Arrays.sort(values, new Comparator<int[]>(){
    public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2) {
        return (Integer.valueOf(o1[0]).compareTo(o2[0]));
    }
});

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(values));
```

The output is the same as the input. I think that the error comes from the `compare` method but I don't know what it is. What is it?

Comment: `values` contains two elements. `Arrays.sort` rearranges those two elements according to the comparator. And in this case the first element `{1, 5, 3}` is indeed smaller than `{4, 6, 2}` so the order isn't changed.

Comment: You could transpose the array first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26197466/transposing-a-matrix-from-a-2d-array sort and then transpose it back.

Comment: Is there no way of sorting the 2D array as it is, without having to transpose it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your comparator logic as you only compare the values along the same columns of different rows and not the different columns of same row.

What you should be doing instead is something like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
{
    int[][] values = {{1, 5, 3},
                      {4, 6, 2}};

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {                  
        for(int j = i + 1; j < 3; j++) {
            if(values[1][i] > values[1][j]) {
                swap(values,0,i,j);
                swap(values,1,i,j);
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void swap(int[][] values,int row,int x, int y) {
    int temp = values[row][x];
    values[row][x] = values[row][y];
    values[row][y] = temp;
}
```

You'll have to change your comparator logic appropriately.

Comment: If `values` has more than 2 rows your bubble sort will not work correctly since you only perform one iteration. You have to keep iterating until everything is sorted.

Comment: @SpiderPig I know but the questions says, *"I want to sort a 2x3 array by the second row in ascending order."*

Answer (score 0):

please, try this, will work ,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] values = {{1, 5, 3},
                {4, 6, 2}};

        for(int i = 0 ; i < values.length; i ++){
            for(int j = 1 ; j < values[i].length ; j ++){
                if(i != 0){
                    if(values[i][j-1] > values[i][j] ){

                        for(int k = j;k>0;k--){

                            if(values[i][k-1] > values[i][k] ){
                                 int temp1 = values[i][k-1];
                                 values[i][k-1] =  values[i][k];
                                 values[i][k] = temp1;
                                 int temp2  = values[i-1][k-1];
                                 values[i-1][k-1] =  values[i-1][k];
                                 values[i-1][k] = temp2;
                            }

                        }


                    }
                }
            }
        }


        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(values));

    }
```

**Out-Put :**

```
[
 [3, 1, 5], 
 [2, 4, 6]
]
```

Comment: It only works if `values` is small. Your are not implementing bubble sort correctly.